# what are the command to send my local react app files to Github repository in VsCode?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, github-actions

i want to know how i can send my local react app folder to my github profile and I don't know which command to use, push and pull are kinda of self-explanatory but All those staging area , commit really got me confused and I have watch videos on Youtube but no one seems to be getting to the point.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to ceate a new repository on github, then just copy the command lines for your case (so under something like "push an existing repository")

open a terminal in vscode and paste them, if this doesn't work for access right reasons etc ...

type this in your command line :

```
ssh-keygen -o -t rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

then go back to github -> settings ->  SSH and gpk key :https://github.com/settings/keys
add a new ssh key (name it as you want) and paste your id_rsa.pub

then try again the command that failed for github